# Python program to create a 3X4X6 3D matrix wiith below elements using loop

Tags: python-3.x, list, matrix

Output I need:

```
[   [[0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0]],
    [[0,0,0,0,0,0],[1,1,1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2,2,2],[3,3,3,3,3,3]],
    [[0,0,0,0,0,0],[2,2,2,2,2,2],[4,4,4,4,4,4],[6,6,6,6,6,6]]
]
```

I am not getting above output

```
    array1 = [[ [0 for col in range(6)]  for col in range(4)] for row in range(6)]
    print(array1)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 problems in your proposed code that we can fix:

1. The 0 being used in the list will make all elements 0. This needs to be changing with the row and the column. We can see that the elements are row*column.
2. The col variable is being repeated. It is good practice to have a different variable name for each nested-for-loop as this will avoid overwriting the values.
3. The row iteration is range(6) but needs to be range(3) as there are only 3 rows not 6.

The code would then look like this:

```
list_1 = [[[col*row for i in range(6)]  for col in range(4)] for row in range(3)]
```

As you can see the 'i' for loop is not being used. Therefore we can use idiomatic python to optimise...

```
 list_1 = [[[col*row]*6 for col in range(4)] for row in range(3)]
```

If you now want to print the list in a more readable format, you can use pprint instead of print like this:

```
 from pprint import pprint
 list_1 = [[[col*row]*6 for col in range(4)] for row in range(3)]
 pprint(list_1)
```

Keep up the great work learning python. It might be hard at first but don't give up and you will be a pro soon. All the best.